# Target load plan in Informatica Cloud, Multiple (Two) pipelines in one mapping

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I made two pipelines in one mapping, one for delete and other for insert as per the business requirement.

The required order of execution is

> 1. Delete
> 2. Insert

I feel it's something similar to target load plan in Informatica Powercenter

Can I execute my delete pipeline first and then the insert one in **Informatica Cloud (IICS)**

Answer (score 0):

The order of pipelines is not guaranteed in ICDI. To do this, create two mappings and use a task flow to define the order.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the order you create your targets.
you can try :

```
                   -->delete target
```

incoming transformation
                       -->insert target